# Interface with keys declared by string array

Tags: typescript

I have an interface.

```
interface ICalculateFieldProps {
  fields: string[]
  set: string
  updateFunc: (valuesObj: object, oldValue: any) => any
}
```

I want `valuesObj` keys to be limited to `fields: string[]` items.

So for example, if pass `['width', 'height']` to `fields`.
Then `valuesObj` must be

```
{
  height: any
  width: any
}
```

Comment: To add information to the question, please use the "edit" link on the question, rather than using comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...if pass `['width', 'height']` to `fields`...

If you mean **at runtime**, you can't do this using TypeScript's type system. TypeScript does its work at compile time.

You can, of course, do it at runtime with runtime checks in the implementation of `updateFunc`:

```
// ...in a class implementing the interface...
updateFunc(valuesObj: object, oldValue: any): any {
    if (Reflect.ownKeys(valuesObj).some(key => !this.fields.includes(key))) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid property ${key} found in valuesObj.`);
    }
    // ...
}
```

...though it would probably be better if `fields` were a `Set` rather than an array.

Comment: You are right about Set.
I have a React component where I pass `fields={['width', 'height']}`. They are never dynamically calculated and I thought that I can check this restriction with generic or something like this.